# Model.remove() is not working at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using expressjs (version 3.10.10), mongoose (version 3.10.10) and mLab.

Here is my code,

```
app.get("/deleteDevice/:query", function(req, res) {

    var query = req.params.query;
    query = JSON.stringify(query);

    vehicleSchemaModel.remove({ deviceID: query }, res.redirect("/devices"));
    vehicleSchemaModel.findOneAndRemove({ deviceID: query }, res.redirect("/devices"));
});
```

As you can see I have tried two methods to delete a document as per this [document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html), however none of them worked.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise

```
 vehicleSchemaModel.remove({ deviceID: query })
 .then(returned => res.redirect("/devices"))
 .catch(err => {console.log(err) })
```

or callback

```
vehicleSchemaModel.remove({ deviceID: query }, function(err, doc){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  res.redirect("/devices")
})
```

Check errors in console. It is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, both of your solution worked after commenting the stringifying line. Using promise shows a DeprecationWarning, though.

Comment: Deprecation warning is expected. Try adding something like `mongoose.Promise = Promise` where you set up your mongoose schema (or after you require mongoose or after the mongoose connection. The point is you have to add that to get rid of the warning,). Doing something like that tells mongoose how to use a promise and this case your a telling it to use regular JS Promise instead of a promise library or non at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
vehicleSchemaModel.find({ deviceID: query }).remove(res.redirect("/devices"));
```